# Standard Input and Command line file in Fortran77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I've been given the challenge to port a Fortran 77 program into C#.
I've found out that read(5,*) read from the standard input, i.e. the keyboard.

Now I'm trying to understand how the following works:

<del>1. When I run the program, I have to run it as `cheeseCalc<blue.dat>output.txt`
, which read a blue.dat file and produces a output.txt file. How does read work in this case?</del>

2. In the same program, there is `READ(5,* )IDUM` and later it also has `read(5,*)idum,idum,tinit`. What is happening in this case?

The blue.dat file has the following lines:

```
HEAD make new cake 
INPUT VARIABLES 
MFED  MASS-FEED 30            ;1001 1 100 PEOPLE TO FEED 
TOVE  TEMP-IN-OVEN 150.0         ;1001 20 100 TEMPERATURE OF OVEN, C
```

*UPDATED*: Just for context, the initial lines of code in the program are:

```
       program cheeseCalc
       CHARACTER*76 IDENT
       CHARACTER*1 IDUM
       READ(5,104)IDENT
104    FORMAT(4X,A)
       READ(5,*)IDUM
c      write start record
       write(6,102)IDENT
102    format('**START',/,4X,A,/)
       read(5,*)idum,idum,frate
110    format(f10.0)
       frate2=frate/3.6
       read(5,*)idum,idum,tempo
       * Do calculation *
       write(6,*)frate2,tempo
       end
```

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: You should show a piece of code showing all the read statements in sequence and also the declarations of all variables being read.

Comment: For (1), note that your program isn't doing anything with the command line: the contents of the file will be read from standard input.  Beyond that, I think the best place for the very basics of the `read` statement is a textbook/tutorial rather than an SO Q&A.

Comment: Thanks, @francescalus. Like I've mentioned, I did read through tutorials about READ(*,*) but still couldn't figure out question 2. Any comment or advice on that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full detail of the general `read` statement is documented elsewhere, but there is an idiom here which is perhaps worth elaborating on.

The statement `read(5,*) ...` is list-directed input from the external unit number `5`.  Let's assume (it's not guaranteed, but it's likely and you seem happy with that for your setup) that this external unit is standard input.

The idiomatic part is the repeated use of a single variable in an input list such as

```
read(5,*) idum, idum, ...
```

This (and the fact that `idum` is an (awfully named) length-1 character variable) signifies that the user doesn't care about the input in the first two fields).  The first string, delimited by blanks, is read then the first character is assigned to `idum`.  Then `idum` is immediately set to the first character of the next string.

The purpose of this is to set the place in the record to the third field, which is read into the (real) variable `frate` (in the first case).

Equally

```
read(5,*) idum
```

is just skipping the second line (strictly, reading the first character, but that's not used anywhere before the next read into `idum`): the first blank-delimited field is read but the next read moves on to the next line rather than continuing with that one.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus for the answer. It looks like I have a lot of work to do!